# DATE(column) filter returns nothing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

If I run the following query directly in `phpmyadmin` I get the desired result

```
select * from trips where route_from = 'CityA' and route_to = 'CityB' and DATE(start_date) = '2015-04-07'
```

But if I run it as PHP code, it returns an empty result

```
Trip::whereRouteFrom('CityA')
                ->whereRouteTo('CityB')
                ->where(\DB::raw('DATE(start_date)', '=', '2015-04-07'))->get();
```

The SQL code that the ORM executes is the following (I am getting it through `->toSql()`):

```
select * from `trips` where `route_from` = ? and `route_to` = ? and DATE(start_date) is null
```

Now, I guess the problem is in `DATE(...) is ...`. When I run the SQL code with `is` in phpmyadmin, it gives me syntax error. With `=` works fine. But the framework generates it with `is`, so I am not sure whether that's the problem or there is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo, instead of:

```
->where(\DB::raw('DATE(start_date)', '=', '2015-04-07'))->get();
```

you should use:

```
->where(\DB::raw('DATE(start_date)'), '=', '2015-04-07')->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use `whereRaw`?

If so the code should look right this.

```
Trip::whereRouteFrom('CityA')
                ->whereRouteTo('CityB')
                ->whereRow('DATE(start_date) = "2015-04-07"'))
                ->get();
```

Or if you want to pass dynamic value you can pass it at the second parameter.

```
$date = "2015-04-07";
Trip::whereRouteFrom('CityA')
                    ->whereRouteTo('CityB')
                    ->whereRow('DATE(start_date) = ?', array($date) )
                    ->get();
```

Comment: The problem that I had was a typo (as the accepted answer suggests), but I really like your solution! :)